# Applying In-line Styles To Div's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, html-email

Is it possible to apply an in-line style to a div in an email? Or is it just classes that can't have in-line styles applied to them?

I've been using `roadie` to automatically generate the inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using tables and not divs for html-email. It is far more consistent across email clients and is widely considered the best practice for html email. However, inline styles can and should be used in both.

On a side note: With tables in mind, if there is an html way to declare it (in the table or td tag), you typically should favor that. Example: `width="100"` works more consistently across email clients than `style="width:100px;"`.

Same goes for height, bgcolor(css background-color), align(css float or text-align), valign(css vertical-align) and border attributes.